# Stuck and confused with $\int \frac{u^{1/2}}{(u+1)^2} du$

Tags: integration, quantum-mechanics

I'm trying to find the expectation value $\langle x^2 \rangle_{\psi}$ for

$$\psi(x,0) = \sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}a \cdot \frac{1}{x^2+a^2}$$

and I know the result is $a^2$. I'm terribly stuck integrating this. Currently:

$$\langle x^2 \rangle_{\psi} = \int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\, \psi^* x^2 \psi \, dx$$
$$= \left(\frac{2a^2}{\pi}\right) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^2} dx = \left(\frac{2a^2}{\pi}\right) \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{a^2} \frac{(x/a)^2}{((x/a)^2+1)^2}dx = \left(\frac{4a}{\pi}\right) \int^\infty_0 \frac{u^2 }{(u^2+1)^2} du$$
where the change of variable $u=x/a$ is used.

With $v=u^2$, $u=\sqrt{v}$ and $du=\tfrac{dv}{2\sqrt{v}}$ and then,
$$\langle x^2 \rangle_{\psi} = \left(\frac{2a}{\pi}\right) \int^\infty_0 \frac{v^{1/2}}{(v+1)^2}dv = \frac{2a}{\pi} \int^\infty_0 \frac{v}{(v+1)^2}v^{1/2} \frac{dv}{v}$$

Then I checked the latter integral in Wolfram Mathematica but the results doesn't seem to match (not $\pi a$) and this is confusing me a lot. Any suggestions with this?

Also: **is it possible to solve it analytically?**

Comment: $x^2/(x^2+a^2)^2$ is a rational function, it should be possible to find an antiderivative by partial fractions. Ort maybe by $x=a\tan z$.

Comment: https://www.integral-calculator.com/

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I was missing a factor $a$ in the normalization term... I appreciate it!

Comment: Re. evaluating $\int \frac{v^{1/2}}{(v+1)^2}\,dv$: put $z=\sqrt{v}$ and it works nice and good.

Comment: Your expected answer of $a^2$ is wrong by dimensional analysis. Use $\int_{-\infty}^\infty\psi^\ast\psi dx=1$ to double-check the normalization constant.

Comment: @holahola: You are missing a factor $a$ in your normalization factor. As J.G observes, you want $\psi^*\psi$ to integrate to one. if you work out the integral you see that the normalization factor is $\sqrt{\frac{2a^3}{\pi}}$, not $\sqrt{\tfrac{2}{\pi}}a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The term $\langle x^2\rangle_\psi$ as defined by the OP can be obtained through standard method of integration of rational functions.

Here is one method:

$$
\int \frac{x^2}{(x^2+a^2)^2}\,dx =\int \frac{dx}{x^2+a^2} -a^2\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^2}
$$

Setting $I_n=\int\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^n}$, we get by integration by parts the recurrence formula
$$ I_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2na^2}\frac{x}{(x^2+a^2 )^n}+\frac{2n-1}{2na^2}I_n$$
For $n=1$ we obtain
$$ I_2=\frac{1}{2a^2}\frac{x}{x^2+a^2} +\frac{1}{2a^3}\arctan(x/a) + C $$
Putting things together, we het

$$
\frac{2a^2}{\pi}\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{x^2\,dx}{(x^2+a^2)^2}=\frac{2a^2}{\pi}\Big(\frac{1}{2a}\arctan(x/a)-\frac{1}{2}\frac{x}{x^2+a^2}\Big)\Big|^\infty_{-\infty}=a
$$

---

The OP, through a couple of change of variables, reduced the quantity of interest to calculating the integral $$\int^\infty_0 \frac{u^{1/2}}{(u+1)^2}\,du=\int^\infty_0 \frac{u}{(u+1)^2}u^{1/2}\,\frac{du}{u}$$
This integral can be obtained by calculus of residues. In this instance, the [Mellin transform](https://academiccesspit.wordpress.com/2013/04/28/evaluation-of-mellin-transforms-via-residue-calculus/) comes to mind (See **Marsden's** basic complex analysis, or **Lang's** complex analysis).

---

The Mellin transform of a function $f$ is defines as $M_f(s)=\int^\infty_0 f(x) x^s\,\frac{dx}{x}$, $s>0$. Under  the following conditions

1. $f$ is analytic on the complex plane, except for a finite number of poles none of which lies on the positive real axis.
2. There are $0<c<s<b$ such that $f(z)=O(z^{-b})$ as $z\rightarrow\infty$, and $f(z)=O(z^{-c})$ as $z\rightarrow0$
   we have that
   $$\int^\infty_0 f(x) x^{s-1}\,dx = -\frac{\pi e^{-\pi i s}}{\sin \pi s}\sum^N_{j=1} \operatorname{Res}_{z_j}(f(z) z^{s-1})$$
   where $z_1,\ldots, z_N$ are the poles of $f$ in $\mathbb{C}\setminus\{0\}$, and $z^{(s-1)}=e^{(s-1)\log z}$ with $\log$ is the logarithmic function with branch $0<\operatorname{arg}(z <2\pi$.

---

For the integral in the OP, it is easy to check that $f(z)=\frac{z}{(z+1)^2}$ satisfies condition (1) and (2) with $s=1/2$.

$g(z)=f(z) z^{1/2 -1}$ has a pole at $z=-1$, and

$$\operatorname{Res}_{-1}(g)=1\cdot e^{-\tfrac12\pi i} -(\tfrac12-1)e^{-\tfrac32 \pi i}=-\tfrac{i}{2}$$

Hence
$$
\int^\infty_0 \frac{u^{1/2}}{(u+1)^2}\,du =-\frac{\pi e^{-\tfrac12\pi i}}{\sin\tfrac12 \pi}(-\tfrac{i}{2})=\frac{\pi}{2}
$$
Thus the quantity $\langle x^2\rangle_{\psi}$, as defined by the OP, is
$\frac{2a}{\pi}\frac{\pi}{2}=a$.

---

**Edit:**
It seems that the OP is missing a factor $a$ in the normalization factor.
$$
\begin{align}
1=\int^\infty_{-\infty}\psi^*\psi&=c\int^\infty_{-\infty}\frac{dx}{(x^2+a^2)^2}\\
&=c\Big( \frac{1}{2a^2}\frac{x}{(x^2+a^2)^2}+\frac{1}{2a^3}\arctan(x/a)\Big)\Big|^\infty_{-\infty}\\
&=\frac{\pi}{2a^3}c
\end{align}
$$
implies that $c=\frac{2a^3}{\pi}$. The OP has $\frac{2a^2}{\pi}$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

By parts,

$$\int\frac{u^2}{(1+u^2)^2}du=\int u\frac u{(1+u^2)^2}du=-u\frac 1{2(1+u^2)}+\frac12\int\frac{du}{1+u^2}
\\=-\frac u{2(1+u^2)}+\frac12\arctan(u).$$

Answer (score 2):

If you want to solve it with a substitution, instead of $v=u^2$ take $u=\tan t$, so$$\int_0^\infty\frac{u^2du}{(u^2+1)^2}=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin^2tdt=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$